# Meteor Inline editor for nested object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

would really appreciate if some can help me with this. I have a nested meteor collection that I am looking to create inline editor on. It is all fine till I find out that you can't access index with #each helper.

I am working on Meteor Shark branch.

So I took a look at meteor implementation of Each and saw that there was index there.

This is a code found in each.js

```
addedAt: function (id, item, i, beforeId) {
         addToCount(1);
         id = LocalCollection._idStringify(id);
```

'i' here is the index.

now normally you can access template data by tmpl.data inside the helper. this tmpl is an object that had functions like find, find all, data, etc. How difficult would it be to extend tmpl object to contain the index: i?

I know they are going to implement this feature, and I really hope it's sooner rather than later so I am looking for an easy to do it now.

Let me give you an example of the object.

```
 {
   "doc_schema": "humans",
   "full_name": {
     "titles": "Mr.",
     "first_name": "Name",
     "middle_name": "Bads",
     "last_name": "Last"
   },
   "email": {
     "main": [
       "aa@gmail.com",
       "bb@gmail.com"
     ],
     "personal": [
       "cc@hotmail.com"
     ]
    },
    "mobile": {
      "main": [
        "+12345678",
        "+12345678"
     ],
      "work": [
       "+12345678"
     ]
   },
   "service": [
     {
       "service": "Line Producer",
       "currency": "USD",
       "cost": 3000
     },
     {
       "service": "DOP",
       "currency": "USD",
       "cost": 50000
     }
    ],
   "city": "New York"
 }
```

For now I can easily modify each.js to extend the data of an object to contain the index but if it's an array of strings like with the case of email and phone number then I don't know what to do.

If any one know how should I go about creating inline editor for such object I welcome suggestion.

Comment: Just write a block helper that does the templating/ html in pure javascript, then return the string as a `new Handlebars.SafeString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this third party package from atmosphere: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/repeat-component

It has `$first`, `$last`, `$middle`, `$even`, `$odd`, and `$index` helpers, it can be nested, and the syntax is:

```
{{#for things }}
  {{#for things }}
  <p>{{ $value }}, {{ $even }}, {{ $odd }}, {{ $index }}, ...</p>
  {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

It has a working example at http://repeat-component.meteor.com/

Comment: This looks awesome and it really work you have my eternal thanks. But is there any example anywhere how can I get it to work with cursor? At the moment I just cant get it to work. No matter what I try it always throws errors.

Comment: Edit: I don't know why I just can't get this plugin to work with my use case, so I looked at its implementation and wrote my own helper using this package's idea and manage to get it to work. So I guess I will mark your answered as solved. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Bads interesting why it did not work for you, it should have iterated over the cursor. Or you may then try cursor.fetch() to get it as an array. Hope that helps. We can perhaps work together to solve this and create an issue/pull request on the package's repo for everyone to be happy :)

Comment: @sekan dunno but I saw that the idea is just to pass the object in the each helper and create new object with all those property. Such a simple idea that I couldn't come up with lol.

Comment: Haha, I see the point, it is always the simplest idea that works best!